# Fantasy novel with 2 half-brothers at odds due to curse and get extended life-span due to Fountain of Youth

Tags: story-identification, novel, magic

In 2000 or 2001 I borrowed a fantasy novel from a friend. I only read the first part of it and my recollection is quite hazy.
I would like to revisit it, but I can't remember title or author.
I can't ask my friend anymore since she died in an accident in 2003.

I know the author is a woman. My friend was a militant feminist and ONLY had books by female authors, so that is a given.
The title possibly has the word *curse* in it. It was a quite thick (about 1.5") paperback.

As I recall the book centers around 2 half-brothers who have the same mother. The younger brother is the result of mother having an affair with a pirate lord while she was in captivity by the pirates (held for ransom?). The brothers grow up separately in a sort of pocket universe that is separated from the main world. They are polar opposites and don't get along really well.
Somehow (I don't recall the details) they both end up together in the main world in a desert area and need to work together to survive.
When they are almost dying from thirst they find an ruined city/castle/mansion with a working fountain and they drink from it.
The fountain is magical and grants the people who drink from it a vastly extended life-span (1000 years of youth or something like that).
Whether that is a blessing or a curse is debatable. And it is debated in the story when they discover what has happened to them.

After that they are rescued by a sorcerer (member of a group of and if I recall correctly some members are disembodied and only around in spirit) that needs the brothers to battle a magical creature.
Apparently they are each gifted with some magical talents. One (the older brother) can manipulate Light (lightning, electricity, etc.) the other can do the same with Shadow (illusions, blocking/shielding Light, etc.) The group of sorcerers ask their assistance and provide some training and they are eventually successful in subduing or destroying the magical entity.
However, during/after the fight, the entity places a curse on the brothers that causes them to hate and distrust each other forever.
This curse then drives further events, which I never had a chance to read about.

Another thing that I distinctly remember is that the younger brother is extremely gifted at music. He plays a small portable harp. His music and his Shadow talent can combine to evoke extremely strong emotions or even to manipulate his audience

The novel is possible the first volume of a series. I vaguely recall a sub-title like "Volume 1 of ...." which usually means sequels were in the making.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is [Wars of Light and Shadow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Janny_Wurts) series by Janny Wurtz, I read the first couple of books, and your memory of them is excellent.

From memory you've missed the first (and possibly the second) book, I can't be sure because it's going on for 30 years ago.

- *book centers around 2 half-brothers* Check
- *Pirate father for second* Fiarly sure yes, check.
- *The brothers grow up separately in a sort of pocket universe that is separated from the main world* They grow up in another perfectly valid world, but go through a portal to another.

*Somehow (I don't recall the details) they both end up together in the main world in a desert area and need to work together to survive.
When they are almost dying from thirst they find an ruined city/castle/mansion with a working fountain and they drink from it.
The fountain is magical and grants the people who drink from it a vastly extended life-span (1000 years of youth or something like that).
Whether that is a blessing or a curse is debatable. And it is debated in the story when they discover what has happened to them.* 100% check.

Unfortunately I don't remember anything after that.

The books (from the wiki article)

**Arc I**

- Curse of the Mistwraith (1993)

**Arc II**

- Ships of Merior (1994)
- Warhost of Vastmark (1995)

**Arc III: Alliance of Light**

- Fugitive Prince (1997)
- Grand Conspiracy (1999)
- Peril's Gate (2001)
- Traitor's Knot (2004)
- Stormed Fortress (2007)

**Arc IV: Sword of the Canon**

- Initiate's Trial (2011)
- Destiny's Conflict (September 7, 2017)

**Arc V: Song of the Mysteries**

- Song of the Mysteries (TBA)

Comment: Jenny Wurtz... I have some of her other work (Empire and Cycle of Fire trilogies and Master of Whitestorm) which I all like. I must have read Curse of the Mistwraith. I just went through its description on Wikipedia and it is definitely the book I'm looking for.

Comment: @Tonny When you're sure, stop back and check the answer as accepted.  That makes it more useful for future seekers.

Comment: @CristobolPolychronopolis I will. But I usually give it at least a day before accepting an answer. In this case it doesn't really matter as the answer is 100% correct, but I have had a couple of cases where a better answer showed up later.

Comment: @Tonny: Thanks, also, if someone does provide a better answer, you can then mark that answer as THE answer 

Comment: "I don't remember anything after that." -- yeah, they start out well but become forgettable after a while.